# How do I add a second hard drive (within Virtual PC) without formatting it?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm trying to add a second hard drive within Virtual PC without formatting it.
I followed the [instructions for adding a second hard drive](http://arcanecode.com/2006/12/18/adding-a-second-hard-drive-to-virtualpc-step-by-step/) but when I add go the the Computer Management>Disk Management console it wants to format it.

The reason I want to add this second hard drive is that it has data on it that I want available  to this instance of Virtual PC

Answer (score 1):

The instructions you followed are for adding a new hard drive. The "reason" for your question makes it sound like the second hard drive exists already. The procedure for adding a second disk is slightly different than adding a new one.

Windows wants to format the drive you added because there is no data on it and it is unformated... If you were to attach an existing VHD that was already formated with data on it windows would recognize it and allow you to use it.

Comment: Ah!  Then these instructions should help (how to attach existing HD in Win 7 VPC). I've not tried it because I'm using VmWare instead of VPC now (because of lots of other problems with VPC): http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3571/windows-7-how-to-attach-vhd-virtual-hard-disk-files/